# Can't access to the object after Importing from SVG

Tags: fabricjs

I need to import some collection of simple SVG to canvas and animate after
I dummy, please help me to resolve.

```
// var obj;

fabric.loadSVGFromURL('../img/cars/car'+(i+1)+'.svg', function (objects, options) {

    var obj = fabric.util.groupSVGElements(objects, options);
    obj.setOptions({
        //selectable:false,
        originX:'left',
        originY:'bottom',
        top:ch,
        left:100*i
    });
    can.add(obj).renderAll();;
});
console.log(obj); // EMPTY RESULT OUTSIDE loadSVGFromURL SCOPE
```

Comment: I had a similar problem, including importing a simple object created that was only a blue background and it just would not work. I converted all I had to work with load from json.

Answer (score 3):

`fabric.loadSVGFromURL` is async. Your console output is running before `fabric.loadSVGFromURL` is ready.
Calling `console.log(obj);` within loadSVGFromURL (after can.add(obj).renderAll();) it should work.